# Output for multiple dates (independently)

Tags: sql, date

Is there a way to use a query on different date combinations, without having to change the date for every combination separately?

---

For example, instead of:

```
SELECT COUNT(X) FROM [TABLE] 
WHERE date1 = '21-01-2017' and date2 = '22-01-2017'

SELECT COUNT(X) FROM [TABLE] 
WHERE date1 = '22-01-2017' and date2 = '23-01-2017'

SELECT COUNT(X) FROM [TABLE] 
WHERE date1 = '23-01-2017' and date2 = '24-01-2017'
```

OUTPUT:

```
23
7
25
```

---

So, I want to know the output for the combination.. in one query :

```
date1 = '21-01-2017' and date2 = '22-01-2017'

date1 = '22-01-2017' and date2 = '23-01-2017'

date1 = '23-01-2017' and date2 = '24-01-2017'
```

---

In the most desirable situation I don't want to change each date manually, but have something like:

every combination of

```
((Date1 between '21-01-2017' and '23-01-2017') x
(Date2 between '22-01-2017' and '24-01-2017'))
```

Comment: Well, you said it ! You can use `BETWEEN` !

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui doesn't it give another output, namely:
not 23 7 25, but 55?

The goal is to see the date with the least value, so I want this date range to give 7, but all the try's I have done resulted in 55 or 25. First step is to know the value for each day.

Comment: Good point! Have you tried `GROUP BY date1 HAVING Date1 between '21-01-2017' and '23-01-2017' AND Date2 between '22-01-2017' and '24-01-2017'`, Something like that..

Comment: Forgot about it! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use Case-When for each range of date :

```
 SELECT 
    COUNT ( CASE WHEN DATE1 BETWEEN '21-01-2017' AND '22-01-2017' then 1 ELSE NULL END) AS COL_21_01,
    COUNT ( CASE WHEN DATE1 BETWEEN '22-01-2017' AND '23-01-2017' then 1 ELSE NULL END) AS COL_22_01

FROM [Table]
```

And you will get like this:

COL_22_01 |  COL_22_01

6         |      56